# An update has caused my client's site to be non-existent after new update of Wordpress

Tags: wp-admin, updates, upgrade

I revised and backed up my client's site yesterday without any issues. As soon as I clicked the update Wordpress button the new install started then a few seconds later the following popped up on a new browser : Updated around 12am Sunday 21817. Site  went into immediate  http 500 error. I tried to log into the wordpress wp-admin page and the admin page said that the username was invalid. I'm not sure if the site is in maintenance or is it just nowhere to found anymore within the server. Everytime i type in the website the following comes up. The website isnt working. The website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
WP version before update 4.6.3 The site hadn't been updated in over 2 years.

Comment: The site is not updated in 2 years. Therefore, also try updating ALL plugins/ theme

Comment: This is why you need to take BACKUPS before updating. I hope you have a backup!

Comment: yes i did lots of backups!:)

Answer (score 0):

Restore your old Wordpress install, then try updating again. Some error might have occurred while upgrading, causing the site/DB to be inaccessible. If the error persist, then you might need to do a [manual update of Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update).

Comment: what if i cant log into wp-admin which makes things so much easier if i can log in and correct

Comment: Please follow my instructions exactly.